# Type Data From InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, types, .net

The question is pretty simple: is there any way to get the problematic `System.Type`s from an `InvalidCastException`? I want to be able to display information about the failed type casting in a format such as "Expected {to-type}; found {from-type}", but I cannot find a way to access the types that were involved.

**EDIT:** The reason I need to be able to access the types that were involved is because I have information about shorter names for some times. For example, instead of the type `RFSmallInt`, I want to say that the type is actually `smallint`. Instead of an error message

```
Unable to cast object of type 'ReFactor.RFSmallInt' to type 'ReFactor.RFBigInt'.
```

I actually want to display

```
Expected bigint; recieved smallint.
```

Comment: It appears that John Saunders submitted a request for this feature to [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/350254/invalidcastexception-should-display-or-contain-more-detail) and it was marked as fixed and available in a future release.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution could be to implement a Cast function which gives you that information if the cast doesn't succeed:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        string a = Cast<string>(1);
    }
    catch (InvalidCastExceptionEx ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to convert from {0} to {1}.", ex.FromType, ex.ToType);
    }
}



public class InvalidCastExceptionEx : InvalidCastException
{
    public Type FromType { get; private set; }
    public Type ToType { get; private set; }

    public InvalidCastExceptionEx(Type fromType, Type toType)
    {
        FromType = fromType;
        ToType = toType;
    }
}

static ToType Cast<ToType>(object value)
{
    try
    {
        return (ToType)value;
    }
    catch (InvalidCastException)
    {
        throw new InvalidCastExceptionEx(value.GetType(), typeof(ToType));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that it would be nice to use the original message *as well*. Just pass it into the constructor of your `InvalidCastExceptionEx`.

Comment: Verbatim, almost, to what I was just about to post.

Comment: It serves the purpose, but it has some disadvantages. If the Cast function throws, then the top stack frame of your stack trace isn't going to be very useful (the exception will originate from the Cast function, not the actual offending line). I also suspect the performance isn't great because of the potential boxing and unboxing of types.

Comment: Jon: I believe that will be handled automatically, as the class derives from InvalidCastException.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this kind of thing with a custom exception:

```
public class TypeNotImplementedException : Exception {

    public Type ToType { get { return _ToType; } }
    private readonly Type _ToType;

    public Type FromType { get { return _FromType; } }
    private readonly Type _FromType;

    public override System.Collections.IDictionary Data {
        get {
            var data = base.Data ?? new Hashtable();
            data["ToType"] = ToType;
            data["FromType"] = FromType;
            return data;
        }
    }

    public TypeNotImplementedException(Type toType, Type fromType, Exception innerException) 
        : base("Put whatever message you want here.", innerException) {
        _ToType = toType;
        _FromType = fromType;
    }

}

class Program {

    private static T Cast<T>(object obj) {
        try {
            return (T)obj;
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException ex) {
            throw new TypeNotImplementedException(typeof(T), obj.GetType(), ex);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        try {
            Cast<string>("hello world" as object);
            Cast<string>(new object());
        }
        catch (TypeNotImplementedException ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The message itself gives you that in a format which is reasonable to display. For example:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'.
```

I don't believe there's a *programmatic* way to access the types involved though (and no, I wouldn't suggest parsing the message).

In particular, the [`Data`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx) property has no accompanying information, unfortunately.

So basically, your options are:

- Use the message in its current form
- Change your design to avoid requiring this
- Go down the horrible route of parsing the exception text (not recommended, particularly if you can't easily control the culture being used)

Comment: So you're saying I should just parse the string? That specific format is not guaranteed to be constant throughout .NET versions, is it?

Comment: @feralin: You're just trying to display information, right? So what's wrong with the existing message? That displays the information.

Comment: I'll wait a couple of minutes to see if anybody has a non-parsing way of doing it.

Comment: @feralin: I would personally stick to the original message. Cakez0r's answer will work if you're happy that you can call the `Cast` method *everywhere* this could go wrong, but you could easily miss bits.

Comment: I actually only do the cast in a single higher-order method, which I call in a lot of places, so I'll only need to change the type cast in a single place. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @feralin: Okay, in that case it would be fine.